# WebEx desktop sharing on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, webex

I realize that Webex does not support Ubuntu 11, however I have a website running on my machine that I need to demo for a client and he will use webex.  I need to be able to use the "share desktop" feature to do this.  Is there any dependable way (`gksudo`, java installation, browser, anything) that lets you share your desktop?

I don't care if the audio crashes since we talk on the phone, and it's okay if it cuts out from time to time -- I just need him to be able to see it.

Alternatively, is there an easy way for me to switch to an ubuntu version that *will* allow me to share my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [ScreenLeap](http://www.screenleap.com/), which seems to have a very low setup overhead (it just downloads and runs a Java applet).

Answer (score 15):

After much trial and error, I was able to get WebEx desktop sharing working in 64-bit Ubuntu just by installing a few packages:

1. Remove unnecessary packages [that cause conflicts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/1307823):

   ```
   sudo apt remove icedtea-7-plugin:i386 icedtea-8-plugin:i386 icedtea-netx:i386
   ```
2. Install 32-bit Java, a necessary 32-bit library, the Java plugin, and Firefox:

   - Ubuntu 14.10+

     ```
     sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre:i386 libxmu6:i386 icedtea-8-plugin firefox
     ```
   - Ubuntu 14.04 and below

     ```
     sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre:i386 libxmu6:i386 icedtea-7-plugin firefox
     ```
3. Make sure the correct Java plugin is configured:

   - Ubuntu 14.10+

     ```
     sudo update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
     ```
   - Ubuntu 14.04 and below

     ```
     sudo update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
     ```

Close and re-open Firefox, and WebEx desktop sharing should work.

- **You must use Firefox**. WebEx will not work on Google Chrome as [Chrome for Linux no longer works with Java](https://askubuntu.com/a/497671/18665).
- **If you don't remove and install the exact packages listed above, WebEx will work, but desktop sharing will not work.**

Comment: I had webex working on 12.04, but now I switched to 14.04 I get it to almost work. Everything except the actual screen sharing works. So I go into the meeting and see the other people, but I an unable to see the shared stream.

Comment: If I get a chance I'll test on 14.04, but in the meantime I blogged about some other methods that may work if the above doesn't: [Using WebEx desktop sharing on Ubuntu 64-bit](http://laviefrugale.blogspot.ca/2013/10/using-webex-desktop-sharing-on-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Working fine with 14.04 but I can't see what other people is sharing.

Comment: @balachmar I just tested these same exact steps on Ubuntu 14.04, and they worked fine. It's very important you install the exact packages as listed. I tried with many other combinations, and none of them worked. If you don't have the exact packages installed, WebEx will work but desktop sharing will not work.

Comment: @jmend I have to create a separate comment so you get notified (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45296/206677), but read my previous comment

Comment: works for me under 14.04 64Bit

Comment: Unfortunatley, still no luck:
icedtea-7-plugin is already the newest version.
libxmu6:i386 is already the newest version.
firefox is already the newest version.
openjdk-7-jre:i386 is already the newest version.
sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-javaplugin.so
There is 1 choice for the alternative mozilla-javaplugin.so (providing /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so).
It mentions: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
But I do have Java 64 bit installed for Eclipse etc.

Comment: @balachmar [Someone pointed out a package conflict](http://laviefrugale.blogspot.ca/2013/10/using-webex-desktop-sharing-on-ubuntu.html?showComment=1415182522730#c4707579600169262492) with the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of icedtea-7-plugin, so I've updated my instructions. Not sure if it will help in your case, but can't hurt to try.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much for a working solution.

Comment: Can't get work sharing on 16.04 64Bit

Comment: Can't get this to work on 18.04. Their [help center](https://help.webex.com/en-us/nki3xrq/Webex-Meetings-Suite-System-Requirements) says "Content sharing does not work in Linux versions that use Wayland as their display management system" and I believe the default on 18.04+ is Wayland.

Comment: @Valentas I wouldn't expect this to work any more because Firefox has also removed support for the Java plugin (https://askubuntu.com/a/354406/18665). I'm not even sure WebEx needs Java any more with modern technologies such as WebRTC, but I'm not sure as I haven't used WebEx in years. FWIW, Wayland is not the default display server in 18.04: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/xorg-will-default-display-server-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Answer (score 7):

Thanks bmaupin! For me this also works on a freshly installed 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 (no upgrade from older Ubuntu)

Enabled 32-bit support (see also: http://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/):

```
    sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Installed openjdk and required plugins for Firefox

```
    sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jre:i386 libxmu6:i386 icedtea-8-plugin
```

Set correct Java plugin for Firefox

```
    sudo update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

Run WebEx

- Confirm all questions (trust WebEx domain, allow to use icedtea plugin, etc)
- Screen sharing works for me
- Audio does not yet work for me

Answer (score 1):

So I've struggled with this for years, and finally have a solution.

1. Install Ubuntu 32-bit.  64-bit simply won't work with Cisco's Webex Java plugin.  I fought this for years, and finally gave up.  I installed Ubuntu into a VM using `[testdrive][1]`.
2. `sudo apt-get install icedtea-6-plugin`
3. Join a Webex and have fun sharing your desktop!

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle Java to solve this issue

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open a terminal window. When it opens, copy and paste the command below and hit enter. Input your user password when prompts and it will add the PPA repository into your system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

After that, update package lists via:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install Oracle Java 8, run:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Change the number 8 to 6 (or 7) in the code to install Java 6 (or 7).

While installation, you’ll be asked to agree the license and then the installer start downloading Java file from oracle website and install it on your system.

To set the default Java, run:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Also change number 8 to the Java version you want.

Comment: I tried this and audio is broken, just like with IcedTea -- "The audio device is unaccessible now."