# Enabling java in firefox

Tags: java

I have java installed.  When I run the "java -version" in terminal I get a expected response indicating that I have Jre1.8.0_66 installed but when I try to see if I have java by asking the oracle website it says it is unable to verify.  I'm certain that the solution in simple but every simple solution for me has been quite a task. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the Java plugin for Firefox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/354361/how-to-install-the-java-plugin-for-firefox)

Comment: Personally, I use an add-on known as "Quick Java".  Simple and doesn't require messing with `about:config`

Answer (score 1):

Don't you forget to enable it effectively in Firefox, because after 52 version, you need to create a value at `about:config`

- Type `about:config`at address bar and accept risks :);
- Create a new  Boolean Preference value, by right-clicking on name title.
- Type `plugin.load_flash_only`and set it **false**

Answer (score 0):

I've got Oracle's Java 8 JVM installed, and on my system, the Firefox plugin is available through the Debian Alternatives System (which has the added benefit of allowing you to switch between JVMs) at `/etc/alternatives/mozilla-javaplugin.so`.

If that file doesn't exist on your system, uninstall Oracle's JVM and [reinstall it from the Web Upd8 PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html), then test whether the plugin works in Firefox.

If that file does exist, close Firefox, open a terminal, and run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so
```

Then test whether the plugin works in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal(press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>). 
Become the root user:

```
sudo -s
```

Create a directory called plugins if you do not have one:

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
```

Go to Mozilla plugins directory before you make the symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
```

Create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

Restart your browser and you are good to go. Found it [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml)

You may also want to look at the following: [How to install the Java plugin for Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/q/354361/476968)

Comment: This helped but when I test for java on the Oracle website it now says there is an "error, an exception has occurred".  At least it is doing something now though.  Better than before.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help somewhat :).