# How can I enable JRE on Firefox in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: firefox, java, jre

I'd like to run Supermicro IPMI console which requires JRE but each time I get this error in Firefox:

> ```
> You need the latest Java(TM) Runtime Environment. Would you like to update now?
> ```

I've downloaded and installed java on `/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_261` and in terminal I get

```
# java -version
java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But after restarted firefox I still can not access JRE.

There are some old similar questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/354406/546191) which suggested installing icetea plugin. I did that `sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin`, but the problem persists. I have also followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/56119/546191) old instructions but it did not work

The [official Oracle java test page](https://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) says:

```
Starting with Firefox Version 52 (released in March 2017), Firefox has limited support for plug-ins, and therefore will not run Java. Use the Java Control Panel to find the installed Java version. How to find the installed Java version
```

So I suppose a lot have been changed since Firefox 52 and we need a new instruction if such integration is possible at all. My current firefox is `80.0.1 (64-bit)`

Really appreciate your hints to resolve this annoying problem.

Comment: Using an old SeaMonkey browser seems promising, but I could not figure out how to attach it to the installed java on the PC. The official page sais `Linux Put a symlink to /usr/java/jre<version>/plugin/i386/ns610-gcc32/libjavaplugin_oji.so in your plugins/ directory. ` But where is the plugin directly when I run SeaMonkey as an stand-alone download?