# How to I make Cisco WebEx work with 13.10 64bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 13.10, webex

I'm having a very hard time getting webex to work under Saucy.  Up until now I've been able to just install a java plugin, install ia32-libs, and I was good to go.  With Saucy ia32-libs is gone and it's up to us to figure out which 32-bit libraries we need to install.

So the question is, how do I install WebEx on 64bit Saucy without ia32-libs?

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --set "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" does'n't work, but I think it should be the other way around
sudo update-alternatives --set "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so, if I understand the update-alternatives syntax right.

Comment: Did it like cdupont, but if I start firefox I get this error-messages ./firefox XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/paulsen/firefox32/firefox/libxul.so: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM.

Comment: I was able to get it working in 2 steps with minimal fuss: http://askubuntu.com/a/363400/18665

Answer (score 26):

From [this post](http://blogs.kde.org/2013/02/05/ot-how-get-webex-working-suse-linux-122-64bit#comment-9534), here is a step-by-step method that might work:

1. Install JDK.
2. Configure Java plugin for browser (no need for a 32-bit JDK or Firefox).
3. Start a WebEx to create `.so` files inside `$HOME/.webex/????/`.
4. Check for unresolved `.so` dependencies:

   ```
   ldd $HOME/.webex/????/*.so > $HOME/check.txt
   ```
5. Search for missing libraries:

   ```
   grep "not found" $HOME/check.txt | sort | uniq
   ```
6. Review the libraries; for example:

   ```
   libasound.so.2 => not found
   libjawt.so => not found
   libXmu.so.6 => not found
   libXtst.so.6 => not found
   libXv.so.1 => not found
   ```
7. Find the corresponding packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apt-file
   sudo apt-file update
   ```
8. Locate that package that contains the missing libraries:

   ```
   apt-file search libXmu.so.6
   apt-file search libjawt.so
   ```
9. Install the missing libraries, for example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y libxmu6:i386
   sudo apt-get install -y libasound2:i386
   sudo apt-get install -y libxv1:i386
   sudo apt-get install -y libxtst6:i386
   sudo apt-get install -y libgcj12-awt:i386
   ```

Comment: Can you confirm that you get a lot of these errors in your console: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: .../.webex/1324/libdbr.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`?

Comment: This worked appears to have worked for me based on [test webinar](http://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html)  `sudo apt-get install libXmu6:i386 libgcj14-awt:i386 libXft2:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386`
A few extra packages were also automatically installed: libgcj14:i386 libgmp10:i386

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 I was missing these: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgcj16-awt:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libxft2:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxtst6:i386`

Comment: I don't find anything with `grep "not found" $HOME/check.txt | sort | uniq`. I found "not a dynamic executable" warnings about a number of libraries, so I used `grep "\.so" /tmp/check.txt | sort | uniq | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\):/\1/g'` and it yields `atascli.so atgzip.so atjpeg.so atpng.so libatdv.so libAudioEngine.so libcmcrypto_jni.so libdbr.so libgdiplus.so libmmaud.so libmmsvid.so libmsess.so libtpwrap.so libwbxtrace.so libwelsvp.so welsdec.so` and `apt-file search` is only able to find libgdiplus (already installed), i.e. most of the others are still missing. :\ Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the complete instructions for my future self and those interested. 
The solution is to install firefox 32 bits with Oracle Java 32 bits.

First get firefox 32 bits:

```
wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-27.0.1.tar.bz2
bunzip2 firefox-27.0.1.tar.bz2
tar -xvf firefox-27.0.1.tar
```

Then get Oracle java 32 bits (replace download with latest version):

```
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jre-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz"
tar -xzvf jre-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
mkdir /usr/local/java
sudo mv jre1.7.0_51 /usr/local/java
```

Create and activate the alternative for the java plugin into firefox:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so"
```

Shut down all instances of Firefox if already running, and start 32 bits firefox:

```
cd ~/firefox
./firefox
```

To check the version of java, type `about:plugins` in the address bar. 
It should display:

```
Java(TM) Plug-in 10.51.2
File: libnpjp2.so
Path: /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
Version: 10.51.2
State: Enabled
Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.51.2 for Mozilla browsers
```

Note that when you are done with Webex, you can change back your version of the java plugin to the 64 bit version (if it was installed) by typing:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config "mozilla-javaplugin.so"
```

And selecting the correct entry.

Additionally, it is necessary to install missing webex libraries as described in Russ Lowenthal's answer:

```
cd ~/.webex
ldd *.so | grep "not found"
#get the package containing the missing libraries (example libXtst.so.6):
dpkg -S libXtst.so.6
#install the corresponding package (appending i386 for the 32bits version)
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

Tested also on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, it works.
Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: how functional is Webex under 32-bit FF? can you share your desktop?

Comment: Yes you can share your desktop, eveything works fine.
The sound is perfect, the only problem is that from time to time the java VM and pulseaudio take 100% of their CPU and then the sound gets inaudible. I didn't found a definitive solution yet, but usually closing some applications, restarting the sound or stoping the screen share solves the problem.

Comment: Gave this a whirl, but got stuck on the alternative plugin setup... the first command works, but the second doesn't:

me@X230:~$ sudo update-alternatives --set "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so"
update-alternatives: error: alternative name (/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so) must not contain '/' and spaces

Comment: +1 Note: If you don't want to pollute `/etc/alternatives` (which isn't 32/64bit aware), you can put the plugin into a folder and set `MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/383960/where-is-firefoxs-plugins-directory

Comment: Kendor: corrected

Comment: worked like charm! :)

Answer (score 3):

ldd was not working for me and would return "not a dynamic executable" for the *.so files

```
~/.webex/1424$ ldd *.so
atascli.so:
    not a dynamic executable
atgzip.so:
    not a dynamic executable
atjpeg.so:
    not a dynamic executable
atpng.so:
    not a dynamic executable
```

I had to install these 3 packages to get it to run (replacements for ia32-libs)

```
lib32z1 
lib32ncurses5 
lib32bz2-1.0
```

After that this command helped me find the packages I needed (can take a while)

```
$ for x in `ldd *.so | grep "not found" | sort -u | awk '{print $1}'` ; do apt-file search $x >> packages.txt ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets here but doesn't find the `.webex` folder check the following:

[Cannot start Webex session. Java permission issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409663/cannot-start-webex-session-java-permission-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Go to AWS,  and create a Windows instance.  Install Chrome and the Webex extensions. Make an image.  Whenever you need webex,  just spin up the instance.

TRUST ME,  trying to get a 32bit app working with a 64bit box has caused me SO much trouble. I have wasted a good portion of my life trying,  and the screen share is terrible even when I got it working.  I Write to Webex once every few months and get nothing back.  My Company has moved to Slack,  which works perfectly on Ubuntu,  good call quality and I can share my screen.  However,  we do have to interact with other, not as enlightened companies and webex is needed.  It is SO worth the pennies per month it takes to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer will do this as well, but I am a bit lazy, so I rebuilt the ia32-libs-multiarch package for Saucy and it works for me. All I did was change two dependencies for libglphoto-2 to the current version and repackage the raring package for multiarch.

It is available [here](http://chucktalk.com/2013/11/05/webex-multiarch-support-in-saucy/), at my long-forgotten Word Press site. Don't write as a regular blogger that much primarily because work keeps me busy in Support. Besides, OrangeCrate is long dead because of the same reason. Work keeps me busy, and I credit learning Linux for that.

Anyway, have a nice day. Don't worry, be happy.