# Google chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, tabs

I have follow the instructions from [Webex on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459838/webex-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-please-help) and after that i have problems when i use the Chrome and i have monitor via HDMI in use, when i click on the Folder bookmark it opens on the other monitor where the Chrom is not on that site. Can some one tell way is this happening, and how can i fix it ? It's start to annoying ... I'm not quite sure if i can remove the previews thing i did, installing java etc to fix the Webex, so i need an expert opinion

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone, I'm on a multi-monitor setup on 14.04LTS and anytime I bring down the bookmarks on chrome since the last update it shows the bookmarks on the opposite display.  I don't think WebEX is part of the equation this appears to be specifically a Chrome problem.

Chrome Version 43.0.2357.65 (64-bit)

Comment: No i don't think so too that WebEx have something to do with it, i think Java have something to do? Also im notes now that my watch at top right corner is gone :)