# How can I use Cisco WebEx in 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, webex

I would like to view screen shares and share my screen via WebEx. I have Firefox installed on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). I can join a meeting, but when I try to share my screen or see others' screens, nothing happens. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you can join the meeting, Java (OpenJDK 7) is working correctly. You just need to install the following 32-bit packages:

```
sudo apt install libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libxv1:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220667&page=2&p=13053998#post13053998

(See that thread for details on identifying required packages. You may need to do this again once 14.10 and future versions come out. The relevant links are http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2014/02/07/webex-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10/ and [How to I make Cisco WebEx work with 13.10 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368270/how-to-i-make-cisco-webex-work-with-13-10-64bit) )

Comment: are you using amd64 openjdk version?

Comment: doesn't work for me. Audio devices are not accessible

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/mshkrebtan/407786e334847544b40e7d6a8a53d247 explains how to run WebEx w/ audio and screen sharing under 32-bit Firefox on a 64-bit Ubuntu OS. Many thanks to [Paul Rougieux](https://superuser.com/users/419414/paul-rougieux) who found it!

**Enable support for 32-bit executables**

Add i386 architecture to dpkg architectures but running `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Install the libraries required to execute ELF-32 executables by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

Download the 32-bit Linux [download of Firefox ESR 68](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-esr) (Note: The original instructions called for ESR 54, and if you have that installed, go with it instead). If installing Firefox ESR 68, install it (here using /opt/webex) by running `sudo mkdir -p /opt/webex/ && sudo tar -xjvf firefox*esr*.tar.bz2 -C /opt/webex/`

Install the libraries required for Firefox (i386) to run smoothly:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    libgtk-3-0:i386 \
    libasound2:i386 \
    libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 \
    libxt6:i386 \
    libxtst6:i386 \
    libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 \
    libcanberra-gtk-3-module:i386 \
    topmenu-gtk3:i386
```

**Install 32-bit JRE**

Download Oracle JRE for Linux (a tar.gz archive for x86 architecture) from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and unpack it to /opt/webex/ with `sudo tar -xzvf jre*linux-i586.tar.gz -C /opt/webex/ && sudo mv /opt/webex/jre* /opt/webex/jre`

**Enable Java support in Firefox**

Create symbolic links for the Java browser plugin libraries:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/webex/firefox/plugins/
ln -s \
    /opt/webex/jre/lib/i386/libawt.so \
    /opt/webex/jre/lib/i386/libjawt.so \
    /opt/webex/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so \
    /opt/webex/firefox/plugins
```

Install the libraries required for Webex to run

```
sudo apt-get install \
    libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 \
    libxft2:i386 \
    libpangox-1.0-0:i386 \
    libxmu6:i386 \
    libxv1:i386 \
    libasound2-plugins:i386
```

Create a Firefox launch script

```
cat << 'EOF' | sudo tee /opt/webex/firefox.sh
#!/bin/bash

export ENV_HOME=/opt/webex
export FIREFOX_HOME=$ENV_HOME/firefox
export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=$ENV_HOME/firefox/plugins
export JAVA_HOME=$ENV_HOME/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

#export JPI_PLUGIN2_DEBUG=1

$FIREFOX_HOME/firefox --no-remote -P
EOF
```

This script will start a new instance of Firefox with the ProfileManager. Choose an existing Firefox profile or create a new one.

You might want to specify a specific profile to start with. Just add the profile name after the -P flag.

Don't forget to make the script executable with `sudo chmod a+x /opt/webex/firefox.sh`

You might want to create a symlink, a la: `sudo ln -s /opt/webex/firefox.sh /usr/local/bin/firefox-i386`

**Start a Webex session**

Launch the script and join a Webex session.

If webex.com sends you a jnlp file and Firefox asks what to do with it, just download it. Further, in the Firefox Preferences > Applications, set the action for JNLP files: they should be opened with javaws (Java Web Start) which can be found in /opt/webex/jre/bin/javaws

(Optional) Install the missing libraries required by Webex
Find out what required libraries are be missing (note that the session number may be different):

```
ldd ~/.webex/T30_MC/*.so | grep "not found"
```

You can use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find out which packages contain the libraries.

It is OK to have libjawt.so absent.