# How can I use Cisco WebEx in Firefox on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 64-bit, webex

Looking at [1] it looks like there is a solution for getting webex run on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. However it does not work on Ubuntu 14.10.

Do you have any ideas?

[1] [How can I use Cisco WebEx in Firefox on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488001/how-can-i-use-cisco-webex-in-firefox-on-64-bit-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Check this! http://askubuntu.com/questions/368270/how-to-i-make-cisco-webex-work-with-13-10-64bit

Answer (score 2):

After installing the java prerequisites, I had issues getting screen/application sharing on 15.04 (64-bit) working, even though I was able to log in to the meeting and attempt to start screen sharing (i.e. there are no obvious indications things won't work), so after some digging was able to use the following command to get the required 32-bit libraries installed quickly:

```sh
sudo apt-get install $(ldd ~/.webex/\*/\*.so| awk '/not found/{print $1}' | sort -u | apt-file -l search -f -| egrep -v -- '(lib32z1|liboss4-salsa-asound2|gcc|gcj|jdk|jre|dbg$)'| sort -u| sed "s/$/:i386/")
```

I expect the commands would be very similar for 14.x so hopefully this is of some use to others.

Comment: The following seems to work on 16.04.1: `apt-get install $(find ~/.webex/ -iname '*.so' -exec ldd {} \;| awk '/not found/{print $1}' | sort -u | apt-file -l search -f -| egrep -v -- '(lib32z1|liboss4-salsa-asound2|gcc|jdk|jre|dbg$|-cross$|libx32|lib32)'| sort -u| sed "s/$/:i386/")`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried solution posted [here](http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.fr/2014/05/setting-up-webex-on-ubuntu-1404-64-bits.html) and [here](http://www.emsperformance.net/2013/03/25/making-webex-work-on-64bit-fedora-core-18/)?

Basically go into your `$HOME/.webex` folder, then into a four digit folder, you have a bunch of libraries that cannot find their dependencies, for that use `ldd`:

```
$ ldd *.so | grep not
libjawt.so => not found
libjawt.so => not found
```

You then need to locate and install the package containing that (those) files.

In my case webex runs fine on 14.04 except for the sound on PC which crashes the conference, also I have 7 different versions of libjawt.so on my machine and libdbr.so and libatdv.so seem unable to find, so I may have a path problem that is preventing sound from working.