# WebEx on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: firefox, 15.04, webex

I can't get webex to work. When I click start "Enter Room" it gives me the helpful error of:

> "Your browser, browser version, or operating system is currently unsupported."

I've tried the instructions at:
[How can I use Cisco WebEx in Firefox on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488001/how-can-i-use-cisco-webex-in-firefox-on-64-bit-ubuntu-14-04)
and
[How can I use Cisco WebEx in Firefox on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525886/how-can-i-use-cisco-webex-in-firefox-on-64-bit-ubuntu-14-10)
but there isn't a .webex folder to check for dependencies, clearly they had gotten further than my attempts before asking for help.

Maybe when Cisco say that Webex supports the latest firefox on a 4~5 year old Ubuntu they don't intend for Firefox 39 to work on 15.04.

Comment: I assume you mean Ubuntu **15.04** (and not 15.10 which is not really even in beta). **Can you confirm?** *I think the missing dependency is Java.*

Comment: Yes, 15.04

And java test tells me I have a working java (v8 u45).

Comment: Still hoping this can be reopened!

Comment: Has anyone resolved this?  I have not seen an answer on the google that applies to Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Some information is provided in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31374032

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not specific to that version of Ununtu, I'm seeing it on Ubuntu 18.04.

A workaround is to set up Firefox to remove all cookies from webex.com and .webex.com on exit. The downside is that you need to click through some dialogs every time.

Also, please note that only the "personal room" meetings are affected. Those meetings are insecure because people outside the company can guess the URL. Also, those meetings don't work is the organizer is missing. If you can teach your colleagues to create real meetings, you won't need to clean cookies and click on the bearded man dialog every time you join a meeting.

Comment: I had real issues trying again only last month. I will look at your suggestion the next time I try (Was a little surprised that I posted this question 5 years ago and not last month)