# How to install libjawt.so in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, libraries, webex

I am trying to use webex in Ubuntu 14.10.

I followed another question on this topic. [How to I make Cisco WebEx work with 13.10 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368270/how-to-i-make-cisco-webex-work-with-13-10-64bit).

I need to install `libjawt.so` dependency in my system.

I tried `apt-file search libjawt.so` which shows many possible libraries with `libjawt.so`.

```
gcc-snapshot: /usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcj-5.0.0-15/libjawt.so
gcc-snapshot: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5.0-snap-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
gcj-4.8-jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
gcj-4.9-jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
libgcj14-awt: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/lib/libjawt.so
libgcj14-awt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/libjawt.so
libgcj14-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/libjawt.so
libgcj15-awt: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/lib/libjawt.so
libgcj15-awt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcj-4.9-15/libjawt.so
libgcj15-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcj-4.9-15/libjawt.so
openjdk-6-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-6-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-7-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-7-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-8-jdk: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-8-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
```

I tried installing `gcc-snapshot:i386` causing dependency broken in my system.

I have also tried installing other dependencies but still not working.

Comment: Try with installing JDk file then use the command sudo apt-get install apt-file,
sudo apt-file update. After doing so go ahead with webex

Comment: I have oracle jdk installed but no changes.

Answer (score -1):

http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.com/2014/05/setting-up-webex-on-ubuntu-1404-64-bits.html says that libjawt.so really is not required for webex to be running successfully and I can confirm that as for my Debian 8 host.

I was not able to discover a package which would install the file on place where it would be discovered by dynamic linker.

I've tried to create a symlink, but that's a hack and as we can see is not really required.