# Webex on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dependencies, webex

I'm trying to get Webext to work.  I read this http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Use_WebEx_with_Linux
which tells me to check for missing dependencies via 
`ldd *.so | grep "not found"`

It gives me this list:

```
~$ ldd .webex/1524/*.so | grep "not found"
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libXmu.so.6 => not found
    libXtst.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libXt.so.6 => not found
    libXi.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libjawt.so => not found
    libasound.so.2 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libjawt.so => not found
    libXmu.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libuuid.so.1 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
```

But if I try to install these 'missing' dependencies I am informed that they are already at latest version.  E.g.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.24.30-1ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

So don't know how to get this going.  Anyone have webex working?

Comment: I've tried everything suggested and a bunch more with no luck.  So ended up just running a virtual machine with Windows for webex.  Not ideal but at least I can still use Ubuntu as my main OS here at work.

Comment: [Webex working on Ubuntu with that user agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ev4K.jpg)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394595/140503 may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is not the lack of dependencies in Linux, the problem is the WebEx update a couple of weeks ago.

I read in other blog, that new WebEx is not longer supporing JAVA, reason why is not working for us.

Comment: Yea, I have tried everything with no luck.  Went with VM running Windows just for webex.  Bummer.

Comment: That's just not true. I was able to get it working today, with a fresh WebEx client download. It clearly uses Java.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed **Desktop Share** Webex feature on newly installed 16.04 by this way:
https://askubuntu.com/a/363400

but i replaced 'openjdk-7-jre' to 'openjdk-**8**-jre' and 'icedtea-7-plugin' to 'icedtea-**8**-plugin'

There are still 'not found' files in the webex directory, and audio calls still does not work, but i don't need it (we use skype)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it working pretty well thanks to [Yuri's answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/766856/edit) and some of the others here. I thought I could provide some additional details and explicit steps.

First, I'm running Oracle's JDK 8, installed via [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java), on a 64-bit platform. This works to launch the meeting dashboard, but desktop sharing doesn't work, because WebEx uses a 32-bit foundation. So I added the 32-bit architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

Then I installed the 32-bit packages:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre:i386 libxmu6:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libxv1:i386
```

This pulls in a whole bunch of dependencies. After the packages are installed, the WebEx libraries show all dependencies met (except for `libjawt.so`, which is provided by the JRE):

```
$ ldd ~/.webex/T30_MC/*.so | grep "not found"
        libjawt.so => not found
        libjawt.so => not found
```

Restart Firefox (I'm not sure if this was strictly necessary, but I wanted to be sure it got all the new libraries). After this, I was able to join my meeting and see the shared desktop. I haven't yet tried audio, as the meeting I was in didn't have web audio enabled.

Comment: For viewing a webex recording, in addition to the above, I had to install libcurl3-dev:i386 (sudo apt install libcurl3-dev:i386).

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach following by

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and restarted firefox.

Comment: I tried this and installed firefox:i386 but still get: 

We've hit a glitch in processing your request.
Try again a little later.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre:i386
```

The above command should fix most of the issue, if not all of it. I also did the below to finish it off.

```
apt-get install libuuid1:i386 libasound2:i386 libxt6:i386 libxmu6:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the following:

**OPTION 1**

```
sudo apt-get -y remove icedtea-7-plugin:i386 icedtea-netx:i386
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jre:i386 libxmu6:i386 icedtea-8-plugin firefox
sudo update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

**OPTION 2**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And now I can open the WebEx just fine, but I am unable to use the audio option, and I cannot see what others are sharing, does anybody knows if this can be fixed in Ubuntu 16.04?