# Webex on Ubuntu 18.04 step-by-step guide

Tags: 18.04, proprietary, webex

Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide to have Webex working on Ubuntu 18.04? I would like to participate in Webex meetings and share my screen.

Comment: Will the answers on that post work for 18.04? That post is on 16.04. And the mentioned Chrome solution does not seem to allow screen sharing.

Comment: You don't know if it works before trying! You can edit your question if it doesn't work or answer it instead if it works.

Comment: According to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033621/webex-on-ubuntu-18-04) I won't be able to share my screen on Ubuntu 18.04 unless I do something that it is not explained in detail. That is why I ask for a step-by-step guide for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Xorg is enabled by default in 18.04, so if you haven't switched to Wayland manually, you are running Xorg. However, that didn't seem to be the problem in the mentioned post either.

Comment: Thank you everyone! It worked!
The answer from @mcarans at https://askubuntu.com/questions/893215/how-do-i-get-webex-working-with-audio-on-ubuntu
does work on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: There is a problem. The other end can see my shared screen, but they cannot ask for permission to take control. How can I let them take control?