# Webex-addon not working @ chrome|firefox/Ubu 20.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, webex

I added the webex chrome extention and the firefox addon. On both i go to

```
 www.webex.com/test-meeting.html
```

and click at **join**. The follwoing msg comes:

```
 Your browser, browser version, or operating system is currently unsupported.

      For details, check the *system requirements*.
```

When i click on the link (system requirements) it sends me to the standard help center.

Most similar problems on the web are for older ubuntu, like < 18.xx. I am using Ubu 20.04, 64bit, Cisco Webex Chrome/firefox Extension Version 1.8.0, Updated last on June 2, 2020. Audio/camera work fine under MS Teams (for linux).

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Additional Info:  I am using Google Chrome
Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) and ffox 76.0.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting from this thread:
[WebEx on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033621/webex-on-ubuntu-18-04)

---

> Given that I'm in an academic environment and our institution uses
> WebEx, I've kept at this problem and think I've solved it in an
> incredibly easy way.
>
> My system - System76 galp3-pro (GalagoPro); Intel Core i7-8565U; Mesa
> Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2); 32 GB RAM - Running Ubuntu 18.04.4
> LTS AMD64 (not Pop_OS) - Running the latest Intel Video Drivers from
> GIT ([https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)) -
> Using XServer-Xorg for the session, not Wayland - Using UNITY 7 as
> window manager (from the UNITY Maintainers PPA)
>
> Steps to get WebEx working:
>
> 1. Using Firefox 74.0; download USER-AGENT SWITCHER (https://mybrowseraddon.com/useragent-switcher.html) from the FF
>    Add-Ons Using the UAS; choose "Windows 10" as the Operating System and
>    "Chrome" as the browser.
> 2. Navigate to WebEx Test Meeting and join a test meeting. The WebEx website should permit the automatic downloading of the Chrome Plug-In
>    and you should now be able to use WebEx as a native Windows10/Chrome
>    user would. Native microphone, sound, webcam worked.

---

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Chromium and Google Chrome it works in the same way:

1. Install [*User-Agent Switcher* addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/dbclpoekepcmadpkeaelmhiheolhjflj)
2. Switch it to Chrome on Windows
3. Use Cisco WebEx

---

For Firefox:

1. Install [*User-Agent Switcher* addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/)
2. Switch it to Firefox on Windows
3. Use Cisco WebEx

Comment: couldn't get webex to work after installing the firefox webex extension on ubuntu 20.04lts... allows username input, but password input is dead link. The webex for linux app appears not to support ubuntu (only deb/rpm)  :-\
Couldn't get webex app to install on windows7, but will work with firefox on windows7 w/o webex firefox extension...