# Is there a way to open Webex on Opera?

Tags: opera, webex

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS on my machine, and I prefer to use Opera as my web browser. However, I cannot watch my lectures on Webex. It says

```
Your operating system or browser doesn't support the Webex Meetings app. Sign in on a Windows or Mac computer to download the app.
```

I also installed the Webex extension of Chrome to Opera using another extension that allows Opera to install Chrome extensions but it didn't work. Does anyone have a work-around? Thanks.

Note: Webex works on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: There is a small commentary on the subject [here](https://rasmushaslund.com/fix-it/webex-issues-opera-browser-step-1-2-add-webex-chrome/), but this site is about Ubuntu and related issues.  Your problem is in the interaction of Opera and Webex, and you may find answers there, that you will not find here.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks! However, as I already mentioned in the post, "I also installed the Webex extension of Chrome to Opera using another extension that allows Opera to install Chrome extensions but it didn't work.".

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1271158/66509 (for webex training) and https://askubuntu.com/a/1270456/66509 (for webex meeting, likely).

Comment: @N0rbert it looks very promising. I have checked it with Webex test but it didn't work. After, I have tried the Webex test with Firefox but it did not work either :) I will see if it works in couple of days. I will edit the post accordingly! Thanks.

Comment: @karel this is the same post that is mentioned by N0rbert in the previous comments, and it did not work. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution on the first link that is suggested by N0rbert at the comments section of the original post did not work. However, this Opera extension [here](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/user-agent-switcher-8/) worked pretty well, even without having to install Chrome extension for Webex. I just selected Windows10+Chrome from the extension, and now I am able to connect to the Webex from Opera on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Thanks for the extension! I open a new opera window and apply the user agent only for that window. It is so frustrating how even If I choose Linux/Chrome user agent it works (even without webex extension) but wont work for plain Opera..

Comment: @theo haha I did not know that Linux/Chrome user-agent also works, its kinda funny. Have a good day.